# Getting not a function error, external script not loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to use an `input mask` script on my site. When I reference function from the external script I get the error `$(...).inputmask is not a function`. I'm thinking this may be because the script isn't being loaded first; however, I implemented [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org) and the issue persists.

The two ways I've loaded the script:

I originally loaded the script straight from my server:

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery.inputmask.bundle.js' %}"></script>
```

Then Method 1:

```
<script data-main="{% static 'jquery.inputmask.bundle.js' %}" src="{% static 'require.js' %}"></script>
```

Now Method 2:

```
<script data-main="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js" src="{% static 'require.js' %}"></script>
```

I'm referencing the source in my script with:

```
$(":input").inputmask();
$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});
```

I trouble shot a bunch of things that haven't worked but think I might just be overlooking a small thing. Any ideas?

I've also tried implementing:

```
  <script> $("#txt").inputmask({"mask":"(999) 999-9999"}); </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
```

Which results in `TypeError: $("#txt").inputmask is not a function. (In '$("#txt").inputmask({"mask":"(999) 999-9999"})', '$("#txt").inputmask' is undefined)`

Comment: are you able to see your referenced file in `dev tool` of your browser?

Comment: @NnN yes I am able to see it in the sources via dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give the `inputmask.js` reference and then give `jquery.inputmask.js`, this should work for `input-mask plugin`.

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kg05w69/).

For more refernce: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/1029

```js
$("#txt").inputmask({"mask":"(999) 999-9999"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>


<html>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
</html>
```

Comment: This results in `TypeError: $("#txt").inputmask is not a function. (In '$("#txt").inputmask({"mask":"(999) 999-9999"})', '$("#txt").inputmask' is undefined)`. editing the question to show my implementation.

Comment: Snippet & Fiddle works, give references in sequence order, 1. JQuery, 2. Inputmask.js & 3. jquery.inputmask.js.